# Why wp_mail() does not work on localhost?

Tags: php, wordpress

I'm trying to make a contact form, but the wp_mail() does not work. I don't receive any messages.I'm  using XAMPP localhost and my code is:

```
 $name    = sanitize_text_field($_POST['yourname']);
 $email   = sanitize_email($_POST['email']);
 $subject = sanitize_text_field($_POST['subject']);
 $message = sanitize_text_field($_POST['message']);
if ( isset( $_POST['submit']) ) {
//check for empty fields
if ( empty( $name ) || empty( $email ) || empty( $subject ) || empty(  $message ) ) {
  echo sprintf( '<h5 class="form_erros">%s</h5>', __('Please Fill All Fields!', 'promag') );
}else {
  // check if input characters are valid
  if ( !preg_match('/[a-zA-Z_x7f-xff][a-zA-Z0-9_x7f-xff]*/', $name ) ) {
    echo sprintf( '<h5 class="form_erros">%s</h5>',  __('Please Enter Valid Name!', 'promag') );
  }else {
    // check if email is valid
    if ( !filter_var( $email, FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL )) {
       echo sprintf( '<h5 class="form_erros">%s</h5>',  __('Please Enter Valid E-Mail!', 'promag') );
    }else {
      // sending the message
      $to = get_option('admin_email');
      $headers = "From:" . get_option("blogname") . $email . "\r\n";
      wp_mail( $to, $subject, $message, $headers, array( '' ) );
      echo sprintf( '<h5 class="form_success">%s</h5>',  __('Mail Successfully Sent!', 'promag') );
    }
  }
}
```

}//endif

Comment: There's nothing in the above code that could give us any idea why the mail doesn't work. Have you checked your servers error log? How is PHP's mail-function configured on your localhost? Using sendmail? Is sendmail installed? SMTP? Have you configured the correct credentials? Please do a bit more research and debugging.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [wp\_mail not working on localhost with MAMP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22254021/wp-mail-not-working-on-localhost-with-mamp)

A quick search also shows https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22254021/wp-mail-not-working-on-localhost-with-mamp

Try the proposed solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's difficult to get mail working on localhost for a variety of reasons which include the SMTP server not being set up correctly.

I would suggest testing with sendmail first and checking to see if that works - if this does not work then I would suggest moving onto testing your local SMTP server using telnet. It could be that you have network issues whereby the ports needed are not accessible due to your internet provider. As far as I know, some ISP's block these ports specifically to help reduce spam.

One potential solution could be to configure PHP to use an external SMTP server like Google via the php configuration file (php.ini).

The best solution, in my opinion, is to get some shared hosting or a VPS and use that to develop on instead.

Comment: This is a good answer, I think, but considering the OP said he is using "XAMPP", that tells me he's probably running on his local Windows PC. There is a reasonable chance there is NO SMTP service installed at all. You can't configure what isn't there! There certainly is no "sendmail". The other suggestions, e.g., connecting through Google or a shared hosting, will solve the issue. Or, he can acquire a Windows SMTP service from somewhere and install and configure that.

Comment: @UncaAlby thanks. Yeah, that is a good shout it could be that there is no SMTP installed but if my memory serves me correctly, mercury mail server is installed out of the box which includes SMTP?

Comment: that may be true -- I've been happily running in Linux for so long now, I've forgotten probably 2/3 of XAMPP!

Comment: Thank you, I haven't tried your solution yet, but your answer seems reasonable enough so I will accept your answer.

Comment: I spent 3 days in atempts to test email service locally,i tried all services and all plugins,mission imposible unfortunatelly.